# ld: unknown options: -sdk_version

Tags: ios, macos, visual-studio-code, actionscript-3, distriqt

[image]

Hello, has anyone encountered this problem? I have no idea and have been searching also everywhere on different sites and forums but I am still lost on how to fix this.

it says:

```
ld: unknown options: -sdk_version

compilation failed while executing: ld64
```

still can't find as of now any other thread that has the same `ld: unknown options: -sdk_version` problem that I have.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: what is your command you are executing?

Comment: Hello @Raptor , I'm trying to build 'debug' and release 'version' using harman sdk / AS3 in vs code in my mac. Unfortunately this error occurs. I hope I answer it well. Sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you may have installed Xcode 15. You'll need to downgrade to Xcode 14.3 until the AIR SDK is updated to support Xcode 15 and iOS 17.

Older versions of Xcode can be found by logging into the Apple Developer Downloads page and searching for the version of Xcode you need. https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/

I reported this issue here: https://github.com/airsdk/Adobe-Runtime-Support/issues/2838

Comment: Worked like charm! Thanks @Michael !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was able to get it working by copying versions from a working project's root build.gradle file:

```
id("com.android.application").version("8.1.1").apply(false)
id("com.android.library").version("8.1.1").apply(false)
kotlin("android").version("1.9.10").apply(false)
kotlin("multiplatform").version("1.9.10").apply(false)
```